# Sending mail as HTML using graph api

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, office365, sendmail, microsoft-graph-mail

I am trying to send mail as HTML using Microsoft graph api but we are getting wrong format email as shown in link screenshot **https://ibb.co/zZ7cn7C**

```
calling graph api as below 

$Body = @"
        { "message" : 
          { "subject": "$subData", 
            "body" : { "contentType": 'html', "content": "$bodyData" }, 
            "toRecipients": [ { "emailAddress" : { "address" : "$MailtTo" } } ],
             } } 
"@ 

#write-output $Body
#Sending the email 
 $sendmail= Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $Headers -URI "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$MailFrom/sendMail" -Body $Body -Method POST -ContentType "application/json"

==================================
when i print output its showing as below link screenshot

**https://ibb.co/jhGn2H4**

Earlier we used to send mails using Send-mailmessage there it going as below 

**https://ibb.co/SrYhCcX**

I wanted to send mail same as above link using Graph api, any suggestions please
```

Comment: Could you share $bodyData? We don't know how the body of the message is formatted.

Comment: SendReport "Certificate expiring in $expDays days" "Do not reply. This is an auto generated Certificate Expiry Notification.`n`nFollowing certificate is due to expire:`n------------------------------------------------------------------------------$($lst|out-string)------------------------------------------------------------------------------`nIf this certificate is renewed already, then update the certificate details at $webLink"

Comment: i am not doing any format SendReport is the function name and passing as parameters, we use to send as same for send-mailmessage its working fine, but when calling graph api its not getting as it is

Comment: When using send-mailmessage, how did you set -BodyAsHtml parameter? Is there any difference if you set "contentType": 'text'?

Comment: send-mailmessage -from $fromAddress -to $toAddress -subject $subData -Body ($bodyData+"`n`nGenerated from: $(hostname)") -smtpServer $SmtpServer -Credential (Get-Credential $creds) -UseSsl -Port 587

Comment: we are not using any contentType

Comment: its working as expected when changed to "contentType": 'text'

Comment: Are you really using the Unix sendmail program as you tagged this?

Comment: The error message is showing the certificate being expired.  You have to fix that issue first before any thing else is done.

Comment: @Rob We are using Microsoft graph to send mails

Comment: Then I removed the sendmail tag for you as it has nothing to do with this.